# Prove that there is at least one value c ∈ R such that the tangent line to f at (c,f(c)) is parallel to the tangent line to g at (c,g(c))

Tags: calculus

Let f and g be differentiable function on R such that f(a)=g(a) and f(b)=g(b) for some a < b.
Prove that there is at least one value c ∈ R such that the tangent line to f at (c,f(c)) is parallel to the tangent line to g at (c,g(c)).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $h := f-g$. Then $h$ is differentiable with $h(a) = h(b) = 0$. Now apply Rolle's theorem.